# TypeScript compiler does not recognize interface method, in spite of it is implemented

Tags: angular, typescript

The code is below.

chart-modal-interface.ts

```
export interface ChartModal {
    onModalInit(data: ChartModalContext): void;
}
```

chart-modal-context.ts

```
export class ChartModalContext {}
```

job-middle-class-modal-context.ts

```
export class JobMiddleClassModalContext extends  ChartModalContext {
    public jobLargeClassText: string;
    public jobMiddleClassText: string;
}
```

job-middle-class-modal.ts

```
export class JobMiddleClassModalComponent implements OnInit, ChartModal {
    ngOnInit() {}

    onModalInit(data: JobMiddleClassModalContext): void {}
}
```

chart-modal.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ChartModalService {
    public show(clazz: ChartModal, data?: ChartModalContext): ChartModalRef
    {
        // .....
    }
}
```

tab-job-type.component.ts

```
export class TabJobTypeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    constructor(private chartModalService: ChartModalService) {}

    public onClickJobMiddleClassPopup(): void {
        const data: JobMiddleClassModalContext 
            = new JobMiddleClassModalContext();
        data.jobLargeClassText = 'largeA';
        data.jobMiddleClassText = 'middleB';
        // error occures at below line 
        this.chartModalService.show(JobMiddleClassModalComponent, data);  
    }
}
```

error message:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof JobMiddleClassModalComponent'
>   is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChartModal'. Property
>   'onModalInit' is missing in type 'typeof
>   JobMiddleClassModalComponent'.

My development environment:

> Angular6
>   TypeScript2.7.2
>   WebStorm2018.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `show` method is expecting an *instance* of `JobMiddleClassModalComponent` rather than the type itself, i.e.:

```
this.chartModalService.show(new JobMiddleClassModalComponent(), data);
```

If you want to pass the type `JobMiddleClassModalComponent` you would have to have an equivalent type to use, for example:

```
abstract class AbstractChartModal {
    abstract onModalInit(data: ChartModalContext): void;
}
```

You could then update your method signature to:

```
class ChartModalService {
    public show(clazz: typeof AbstractChartModal, data?: ChartModalContext): ChartModalRef
    {
        return {};
    }
}
```

And this in turn allows you to call it with:

```
this.chartModalService.show(JobMiddleClassModalComponent, data);
```